# The goalkeeper mistakenly kicks the ball into the goal during kicks from the penalty mark

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

There is [a video of a kick taken](https://www.facebook.com/100001919794807/posts/3657469044327053/?app=fbl) during kicks from the penalty mark.

The goalkeeper dived and blocked the ball from going into the goal. However as the goalkeeper was standing up immediately from the dive, his foot kicked the ball back into the goal and the referee disallowed it.

Is it a goal or not?

Comment: @OlaStrom please do not remove correct terminology. The change to link formatting was also unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty close, but **no goal** is the correct decision. The referee was right when he disallowed the goal.

During kicks from the penalty mark, the kick is completed when the ball

- is out of play
- stops moving

In your video the ball just lays on the ground after the save, so the kick was already completed when the goalie kicked it into the goal.